# AttributeError while trying to get attribute from custom widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a custom widget with a class (myEntry) that inherits from Entry. When I instantiate myEntry, its methods work just fine, but when I try to get its attributes I get an AttributeError instead.

Below is a simplified version of the code. I wrote it just to test this class and try to figure out what I'm doing wrong. If I click on *btTest1*, I get "John Smith". If I click on *btTest2*, I get "This works, too". When I click on *btTest3*, though, I get the following:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Raquel/Documents/Controle de Pedidos/CP2/teste.py", line 15, in <lambda>
    btTest3 = Button(myFrame, text="Get value", command=lambda: print(txtTest.myValue))
AttributeError: 'myEntry' object has no attribute 'myValue'
```

So, it seems I can get the value of the fullName attribute of x (a Person instance) with x.fullName, but I can't get the value of the myValue attribute of txtTest (a myEntry instance) with txtTest.myValue? What am I missing here?

```
from tkinter import *

class main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        x = Person("John Smith")
        myFrame = Frame(self, bd=10)
        myFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        lbTest = Label(myFrame, text="My field*:")
        vTest = StringVar()
        txtTest = myEntry(myFrame, vTest, "testing")
        btTest1 = Button(myFrame, text="Get full name", command=lambda: print(x.fullName))
        btTest2 = Button(myFrame, text="Show", command=lambda: txtTest.show())
        btTest3 = Button(myFrame, text="Get value", command=lambda: print(txtTest.myValue))
        lbTest.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        txtTest.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        btTest1.grid(row=1, column=0)
        btTest2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        btTest3.grid(row=1, column=2)

class myEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master, myVar, myValue):
        super().__init__(master, textvariable=myVar)
        self = Entry(master, textvariable=myVar)
        self.myValue = myValue

    def show(self):
        print("This works, too.")

class Person():
    def __init__(self, fullName):
        self.fullName = fullName

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    main(root).pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because of the line -

```
self = Entry(master, textvariable=myVar)
```

You are changing the local variable `self` to a new `Entry` object that you create, and then setting the `.myValue` attribute for it. The original `myEntry` object does not have that attribute, only the new `Entry` object that you create has it, but it just gets discarded after this.

You really do not need the above line, just the line `super().__init__(master, textvariable=myVar)` is good enough. You can remove the line - `self = Entry(master, textvariable=myVar)` . Example -

```
class myEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master, myVar, myValue):
        super().__init__(master, textvariable=myVar)
        self.myValue = myValue
```

Comment: And just like that, everything works now. Thank you.